# Cheap and small alternative to optoisolators: is there any?

Tags: opto-isolator, isolation

Typical opto has several kV isolation voltage (which is not always needed), has relatively big cases ([TLP291](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/toshiba-semiconductor-and-storage/TLP291(GB-TP,E)/TLP291(GB-TPE)CT-ND/3053062) in 4-SOIC is one of the smallest as I know) and typical price up to 1 USD in small amounts (not cheap in my case).

In my case I'd be satisfied if I'd be able to transmit a signal with as low as 350VDC (250Vrms) isolation. There are no safety reasons (I just need to transmit the signal from neutral to line).

At the receiving side the signal should be something similar to a switch (like collector-emitter of the opto): "on" or "off". This signal will drive MOSFET driver. The speed is pretty low (1 ms would be enough).

Capacitor can be cheap and small solution, but it will not work on DC.

So if I don't need such big isolation voltage is there any alternative to optoisolator?

Comment: What signal are you trying to convey? Is there a safety reason to use an "isolator"?

Comment: optoisolators. cheap? check. small? check.

Comment: maybe define "small"?

Comment: Hi, @Andyaka! I put some additional info in my question. Shortly: I need this signal to drive a MOSFET gate.

Comment: @WesleyLee, As I noted 4-SO (TLP291) is big in my case. I'd be happy to have smaller solution. One of the main reason to make optos "big" is the isolation voltage. So if I don't need that isolation I'd hope for a smaller solutions.

Comment: Please state what voltage size/shape you wish to appear on the MOSFET's gate and you might also need to include that part of the circuit. It ma be possible to use capacitors but more information is needed, as per my comment.

Comment: @Andyaka, typical Vgs is about 2V. I will manage the additional schematic but several hours later.

Comment: Cheaper SO4 clones of the PC817 might be EL3H7, LTV-217, HMHA281, PS2801C, PC3H7, or VOS617A. Anyway, this sounds as if you want just a 350 V level shifter.

Comment: How are you goind to supply power to MOSFET Gate? Is it switching fast or slow? If slow - did you consider power dissipation during switching process?

Comment: @CL, if this level shift schematic would work - I'd be happy to consider this solution. Thanks for the optos!

Comment: In what situation do you intend to use this device? What do you need 250Vrms isolation for?

Comment: @Master, yes, I'd like to feed he gate of the MOSFET. I'm aware of the slow switching problems but I will consider this second after I will figure out any isolation solution. Thanks!

Comment: The reason for my question is: for fast switching, you need some power. It can not be delivered (without really bad tricks) by the high side driver or similar circuit. So, to me, the question of switching is the first one!

Comment: There are plenty of optoisolators (photo diode + photo transistor), they are cheap but they are even more bulky than SOIC-8. And, to my experience, you can hardly reduce isolation distance compared to SOIC-8 even for mains 220 V RMS... There is a problem of dust, solder paste remains etc.

Comment: And the worst problem with "digital isolators" (like TI ISO7220...) is not their size. It is the size of isolated power supply you need to drive them and the MOSFET.

Comment: You can try using a trick like: modulate the control signal to 10 MHz or about; use high voltage small MLCC to isolate the gate from the signal source; use rectifier on the gate side to get DC from AC 10 MHz.

Comment: The most difficult part in this design is: how to discharge input capacitance of MOSFET quickly when you want it to go to OFF state.

Answer (score 3):

> There are no safety reasons (I just need to transmit the signal from neutral to line).

Just to be clear, no safety reasons should also mean that no user will be able to access any part of the system that is connected (directly or indirectly) to the "high voltage" system. It also means that the construction of the system is designed for fire safety as if it were all connected directly to the high voltage.

It means that the entire system will be designed as if all of it is at "high" voltage at all times, as far as fire and shock hazards are concerned.

> I just need to transmit the signal from neutral to line

If this means you want to superimpose a data signal on to a mains wire pair, then AFAIK the usual way is to use a transformer. Since relatively low is required, it doesn't necessarily have to be very big or pricey.

> Capacitor can be cheap and small solution, but it will not work on DC.

Finding a solution that works at DC will be very difficult, since mains frequencies are very close to DC compared to the message signal in most data communications situations.

Consider modulating your message signal to some higher frequency to enable separating out the message frequency band from the mains frequency.

Comment: Thank you for the input! Now I have some thoughts to think of. Just have to note: this is not for PLC, this is for switching the mains off and on within smallest size and budget.

Comment: In that case, you can just use a relay or SSR, so that your switching device provides isolation between the switched circuit and the control circuit. In any case, if you don't use isolation you must treat the whole circuit as "hot" from a safety point of view.

Comment: Relays are SO big, SSR needs high input current (typical 10 mA). Thanks!